# How to differentiate such matrix expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Given data $(y_1, ..., y_n)$ and each $y_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$, and $V$ is a $p \times q$ matrix with $q$ orthogonal unit vectors as columns. How do I differentiate the following ? And what is the solution ?

$$\min_{V} \sum^N_{i=1} || y_i - V V^T y_i ||^2$$

Comment: What does $VV^Ty_i$ mean? Are you multiplying the $p\times p$ matrix $VV^T$ by the scalar $y_i$?

Comment: $V\; V^T \; $ corresponds to 2 matrices multiplied together. And $y_i$ is a $p$-dimensional vector.

Comment: I didn't realize that $y_i\in\mathbb{R}^p$. I think the best approach would be to find an analytical expression for the minimum, and then differentiate it with respect to each $y_{ij}$. To find the minimum, differentiate the sum with respect to $V$, and find the $V$ that sets the derivative equal to zero.

Comment: Just to clarify: $q$ is fixed and less than $p$ right? also $n=N$ I guess. $\min_V$ means that you minimizes over any possible $p\times q$ matrix right? and you want to differentate on the variable $y_i$.

Comment: Are you minimizing with respect to $V$ or $y$ ?

Comment: A larger problem here is that by requiring $V$ to have orthonormal columns, the derivatives will inevitably point in directions that are infeasible. That is to say, it is almost certain that $V+\alpha \nabla f(V)$ will fail to have orthonormal columns. So searching for the derivative here is likely not going to be helpful. I think user126154's answer below is on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete anwer but it may help. (It is more a reformulation than an answer but it was too long for a comment)

Briefly, the requested minimum is the sum of the first $p-q$ eigenvalues of the matrix $YY^T$ (see below)

Since the columns of $V$ form an orthonormal system, the vector $VV^Ty$ is just the component of $y$ along the space spanned by the columns of $V$.

If follows that $y-VV^Ty$ is the projection of $y$ to the orthogonal of the columns of $V$.

As a corollary we get immediately that if $p=q$ then the requestet minumum is always zero.

In general if we denote by $y^W$ the orthogonal projection of $y$ over a space $W$, we have $||y-VV^Ty||=||y^W||$, where $W$ is the orthogonal of the columns of $V$. In particular
$$\min_V=\sum_i||y_i-VV^Ty_i||^2=\min_W\sum_i||y_i^W||^2$$
where now the minimum is taken over all spaces $W$ of dimension $p-q$. If $w_i,\dots,w_{p-q}$ is an orthonormal basis of $W$ we have
$$||y^W||^2=\sum_j\langle y,w_j\rangle^2=\sum_j\langle y\langle y,w_j\rangle,w_j\rangle$$

If we denote by $Y$ the matrix which has by columns the vectors $y_i$ we have that $$YY^Tw_j=\sum_iy_i\langle y_i,w_j\rangle$$ 
therefore
$$\sum_i||y_i^W||^2=\sum_{i,j}\langle y_i\langle y_i,w_j\rangle,w_j\rangle=\sum_j\langle\sum_i y_i\langle y_i,w_j\rangle,w_j\rangle=\sum_j\langle YY^Tw_j,w_j\rangle$$

In conclusion, the requestet minimum equals 
$$\min_{w_1,\dots,w_{p-q}}\sum_j\langle Aw_j,w_j\rangle$$

Where $A=YY^T$ ant the minimum is taken over all choices of $p-q$ orthonormal vectors. Since $A$ is symmetric, it can be diagonalyzed by an orthonormal basis. (Note alson that the condition $A=YY^T$ implies that the eigenvalues of $A$ are positives as $\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle Y^Tx,Y^Tx\rangle$)

If we denote by $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\dots\leq\lambda_p$ the eigenvalues of $A$, the requestet minimum is just 
$$\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_{p-q}$$
that is to say, the sum of the first $p-q$ eigenvalues of $A=YY^T$

So the original answer translates as "how can we differentiate the eigenvalues of a matrix of the form $YY^T$ with respect to the components of $Y$?"